# uninitialized constant when trying to use a custom class in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

On Rails 5.1, I have this module:

```
app/datatables/financing/merchants_datatable.rb
```

and in my merchants_controller.rb file,  I have this code:

```
def index
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: Datatables::Financing::MerchantsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
end
```

When I try to run my test/controllers/merchants_controller_test.rb, I run into this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Financing::MerchantsController::Datatables
```

How can I load my merchants_datatable.rb module in my tests?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you have this line in the `spec_helper`? `Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`. What does your folder structure look like? I can tell you right now that the path in the error doesn't match the folder structure or the `render json: ...` line.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby seems to be confused about your module structure. Change

```
format.json { render json: Datatables::Financing::MerchantsDatatable.new(view_context) }
```

to

```
format.json { render json: ::Datatables::Financing::MerchantsDatatable.new(view_context) }
```

to tell Ruby not to start searching for `Datatables` inside of the `Financing::MerchantsController` namespace.